# C# inline sorting ObservableCollection does not update Data Binding

Tags: c#, sorting, mvvm, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a `ViewModel` which contains an `ObservableCollection<CustomKeyGroup<CustomItem>>` property bound to a control in a `View` and the problem is that I want to sort this collection by a property in `CustomKeyGroup<T>`, without setting the `ObservableCollection<...>` object property (i.e. sort the collection inline):

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    ... // data service etc code

    private ObservableCollection<CustomKeyGroup<CustomItem>> _items = new ObservableCollection<CustomKeyGroup<CustomItem>>();
    public ObservableCollection<CustomKeyGroup<CustomItem>> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    public void Sort(string _orderBy = null, bool _descending = true) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_orderBy) || this.Items.Count == 0) {
            return;
        }

        var test = this.Items.ToList();

        // bubble sort
        try {
            for (int i = test.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                    CustomKeyGroup<CustomItem> o1 = test[j - 1];
                    CustomKeyGroup<CustomItem> o2 = test[j];
                    bool move = false;

                    var order = typeof(CustomKeyGroup<CustomItem>).GetProperty(orderBy);
                    var t = order.GetValue(o1);
                    var t2 = order.GetValue(o2);

                    // sort comparisons depending on property
                    if (_descending) { // ascending
                        if (t.GetType() == typeof(int)) { // descending and int property
                            if ((int)t < (int)t2) {
                                move = true;
                            }
                        } else { // descending and string property
                            if (t.ToString().CompareTo(t2.ToString()) > 0) {
                                move = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else { // ascending
                        if (t.GetType() == typeof(int)) { // ascending and int property
                            if ((int)t > (int)t2) {
                                move = true;
                            }
                        } else { // ascending and string property
                            if (t.ToString().CompareTo(t2.ToString()) < 0) {
                                move = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // swap elements
                    if (move) {
                        //this.Items.Move(j - 1, j); // "inline"

                        test[j] = o1;
                        test[j - 1] = o2;
                    }
                }
            }
            // set property to raise property changed event
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<CustomKeyGroup<CustomItem>>(test);
        } catch (Exception) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Sorting error");
        }

        //RaisePropertyChanged("Items"); // "inline sort" raise property changed to update Data binding

        Debug.WriteLine("Sorted complete");
    }

    ... // get data from service, etc.
```

From the code above, the attempted inline sorts are commented out (as they do not update the control that databinds to it), and the manual setting of `Items` are left in (works, but if you scroll down the control and sort, it will take you back to the top - undesirable!).

Anyone have any idea how I can update the view/control using an inline sort option? I've also tried manually raising the `RaisePropertyChanged` event (specified in `ObservableObject` using the [MVVMLight Toolkit](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)) to no avail.

**Note:** Setting a breakpoint at the end of the `try-catch` reveals that the `ObservableCollection<...>` **is indeed** sorted, but the changes just do not reflect in the `View`! Even weirder is that the control (`LongListSelector`) has a `JumpList` bound to another property of `CustomKeyGroup<T>` and **it** successfully updates instantly!! If I tap on any of these items in the `JumpList`, the `View` correctly updates itself, revealing the sorted items... I then thought of setting the `DataContext` of the `View` after sorting, but that also does not solve the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorting a collection in WPF can be problematic. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945461/how-do-i-sort-an-observable-collection?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think my problem relates to WP/Silverlight in general as I am able to sort the `ObservableCollection` perfectly, the problem comes in with the XAML binding. It (the control, LLS in this case) doesn't update after the collection is sorted (inspecting the collection with a breakpoint after sorting reveals it has been sorted).

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Unless you set your ObservableCollection to a newly sorted ObservableCollection, the changes won't be flagged and thus your view won't get updated.

Comment: I see. Quite an odd problem isn't it? I would've thought that _changing_ the collection (by removing some element) would at least update the view (by raising `NotifyCollectionChanged` on the collecton, but apparently not. It simply removes the element from the view, without updating the order! I suppose this makes sense in the implementation of `ObervableCollection` as `Move` raises `CollectionChanged` anyway.

Comment: Indeed. It's very counter-intuitive you cannot change any part of an ObservableCollection and the change is not raised automatically. However, for every hole in WPF there is a third party library out their to fill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my own answer here.

So following the comments from the original post, @piofusco points out that a View does not update when an `ObservableCollection` has only been sorted. Even manually changing the collection (hence, raising `NotifyPropertyChanged` or `NotifyCollectionChanged`) does not update it.

Searching around a little more, I decided I could make use of `CollectionViewSource`, which would do my sorting for me - without changing the collection itself (hence allowing the control to retain its current scroll position). To get it working, basically, add a new property to the `ViewModel` of type `CollectionViewSource`, add a `SortDescription`, set its `Source` and bind directly to that property (instead of the original `ObservableCollection`:

In `ViewModel`:

```
private CollectionViewSource _sortedCollection = new CollectionViewSource();
public CollectionViewSource SortedCollection {
    get {
        _sortedCollection.Source = this.Items; // Set source to our original ObservableCollection
        return _sortedCollection;
    }
    set {
        if (value != _sortedCollection) {
            _sortedCollection = value;
            RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("SortedCollection"); // MVVMLight ObservableObject
        }
    }
}
```

View XAML (note the binding to Property.**View**):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SortedCollection.View}" ... />
```

And in your View code-behind, if you have a Sort button:

```
ViewModel _vm = this.DataContext as ViewModel;
viewModel.SortedCollection.SortDescriptions.Clear(); // Clear all 
viewModel.SortedCollection.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PropertyName", ListSortDirection.Descending)); // Sort descending by "PropertyName"
```

And boom! Your sorted collection should update instantly in the View! Even better is that it retains our `ObservableCollection` functionality in that any updates to objects in the `ObservableCollection` will raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` or `NotifyCollectionChanged` handlers, thereby updating the View (allowing for both sorting and updating of objects while retaining current scroll positions)!

**Note:** For those out there using a `LongListSelector` control, I wasn't able to get it to work, and with a little more internet-digging with I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22112845/2714911), which, discusses *why* LLS cannot bind to a `CollectionViewSource.View` without some modifications. So I ended up using a `ListBox` control instead. You can read about some of the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444927/windows-phone-mango-listbox-or-longlistselector). For my task though, the `ListBox` will suffice.